# AWS RDS snapshot sharing takes too long

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I've shared a RDS manual snapshot between two accounts that I have. And after an hour I still can't see it in the other account.

How long does this normally take?

Comment: What's the size of your RDS instance?

Comment: 1TB. Sharing succeeded after an hour when I shared within the same region (different accounts).

Comment: Sharing from another region didn't work at all. And AWS support were not able to tell why. Typical.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, for a 1TB DB size. This could take *hours*. Or not work at all. 
My only tip would be to first copy to the region you want to share with and then share from there.

AWS said it's suppose to be really fast since data is not actually copied. So they said.

Comment: Another option would be using DB Migration Service. Our DBA was pleased with the performance when he was migrating 1.5 TB from MS SQL on prem to MySQL in RDS through Direct Connect.